# It's possible to access to parent searching by field?

Tags: javascript

I have a big object:

Lets say I would like to find a specific "id" on that object and then return it's parent id.

```js
var obj = {
  "level": {
    "projectHourlyWage": 0,
    "projectTaxRate": 0.19,
    "projectPriceComponents": [
      "Material",
      "Gear"
    ],
    "projectItemNumberSchema": {
      "totalLength": 7,
      "tiers": [
        {
          "length": 2,
          "type": "Numeric",
          "tierType": "Group",
          "isLot": false
        },
        {
          "length": 2,
          "type": "Numeric",
          "tierType": "Group",
          "isLot": false
        },
        {
          "length": 3,
          "type": "Numeric",
          "tierType": "Position",
          "isLot": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "elements": [
      {
        "projectHourlyWage": 0,
        "projectTaxRate": 0.19,
        "projectPriceComponents": [
          "Material",
          "Gear"
        ],
        "projectItemNumberSchema": {
          "totalLength": 7,
          "tiers": [
            {
              "length": 2,
              "type": "Numeric",
              "tierType": "Group",
              "isLot": false
            },
            {
              "length": 2,
              "type": "Numeric",
              "tierType": "Group",
              "isLot": false
            },
            {
              "length": 3,
              "type": "Numeric",
              "tierType": "Position",
              "isLot": false
            }
          ]
        },
        "elements": [
          {
            "unitPrice": 800,
            "quantity": 1,
            "unitTag": "Flat",
            "labourComponents": {
              "label": "Labour",
              "price": 0,
              "hourlyWage": 0,
              "values": [],
              "useOwnHourlyWage": false,
              "totalTime": 0
            },
            "priceComponents": [
              {
                "price": 0,
                "label": "Material",
                "values": []
              },
              {
                "price": 0,
                "label": "Gear",
                "values": []
              },
              {
                "price": 800,
                "label": "",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "formula": "800",
                    "result": 800,
                    "valid": true,
                    "errorPositionInLine": -1
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "quantityComponents": [
              {
                "formula": "1",
                "result": 1,
                "valid": true,
                "errorPositionInLine": -1
              }
            ],
            "subDescriptions": [],
            "comissionStatus": "Undefined",
            "complementedBy": [],
            "complemented": false,
            "amountToBeEnteredByBidder": false,
            "priceCompositionRequired": false,
            "useDifferentTaxRate": false,
            "taxRate": 0.19,
            "itemNumber": {
              "id": "a369d7c8-c281-4a08-9f80-91768aaa3e5d",
              "stringRepresentation": "01.01.001",
              "isSchemaCompliant": true,
              "itemNumberSchema": {
                "totalLength": 7,
                "tiers": [
                  {
                    "length": 2,
                    "type": "Numeric",
                    "tierType": "Group",
                    "isLot": false
                  },
                  {
                    "length": 2,
                    "type": "Numeric",
                    "tierType": "Group",
                    "isLot": false
                  },
                  {
                    "length": 3,
                    "type": "Numeric",
                    "tierType": "Position",
                    "isLot": false
                  }
                ]
              },
              "identifiers": [
                "01",
                "01",
                "001"
              ],
              "isLot": false
            },
            "deductionFactor": 0,
            "totalPrice": 800,
            "totalPriceGross": 952,
            "totalPriceGrossDeducted": 952,
            "deductedPrice": 800,
            "positionType": "Regular",
            "priceType": "WithTotal",
            "serviceType": "Regular",
            "shortText": "Site Preparation",
            "longText": "Preparation of the site before construction start.",
            "htmlLongText": "<span>Preparation of the site before construction start.</span>",
            "additionType": "None",
            "elementType": "PositionDto",
            "quantityAssignments": [],
            "isLumpSum": false,
            "projectCatalogues": [],
            "catalogueReferences": [],
            "complementedByQuantities": [],
            "notOffered": false,
            "id": "ad3c8848-bc89-4549-abe2-a33b79b9f20c",
            "gaebXmlId": "ID_c456cc7e-181d-4367-b56c-d21ee227efa1",
            "elementTypeDiscriminator": "PositionDto"
          }
        ],
        "projectLabourTimeLabel": "Labour",
        "containsDuplicateItemNumbers": false,
        "containsDuplicateElementIds": false,
        "ignoreDuplicateItemNumbers": false,
        "ignoreDuplicateElementIds": false,
        "totalPriceGrossByTaxRate": [
          {
            "taxRate": 0.19,
            "deductionFactor": 0,
            "totalNet": 800,
            "totalDeducted": 800,
            "totalTax": 152,
            "totalGross": 952,
            "totalGrossDeducted": 952,
            "totalTaxDeducted": 152
          }
        ],
        "ignoreChildPriceUpdates": false,
        "deductedPrice": 800,
        "deductionFactor": 0,
        "totalPrice": 800,
        "totalPriceGross": 952,
        "totalPriceGrossDeducted": 952,
        "priceType": "WithTotal",
        "shortText": "General",
        "comissionStatus": "Undefined",
        "itemNumber": {
          "id": "faa27dbb-e255-432f-be59-2d93a2b18078",
          "stringRepresentation": "01.01.",
          "isSchemaCompliant": true,
          "itemNumberSchema": {
            "totalLength": 7,
            "tiers": [
              {
                "length": 2,
                "type": "Numeric",
                "tierType": "Group",
                "isLot": false
              },
              {
                "length": 2,
                "type": "Numeric",
                "tierType": "Group",
                "isLot": false
              },
              {
                "length": 3,
                "type": "Numeric",
                "tierType": "Position",
                "isLot": false
              }
            ]
          },
          "identifiers": [
            "01",
            "01"
          ],
          "isLot": false
        },
        "elementType": "ServiceSpecificationGroupDto",
        "isLot": false,
        "projectCatalogues": [],
        "catalogueReferences": [],
        "id": "402a9267-0d36-412f-84ee-918db077f4bb",
        "gaebXmlId": "ID_b41e1957-1915-4e06-a755-ab9bbdb27908",
        "elementTypeDiscriminator": "ServiceSpecificationGroupDto"
      }
    ],
    "projectLabourTimeLabel": "Labour",
    "containsDuplicateItemNumbers": false,
    "containsDuplicateElementIds": false,
    "ignoreDuplicateItemNumbers": false,
    "ignoreDuplicateElementIds": false,
    "totalPriceGrossByTaxRate": [
      {
        "taxRate": 0.19,
        "deductionFactor": 0,
        "totalNet": 800,
        "totalDeducted": 800,
        "totalTax": 152,
        "totalGross": 952,
        "totalGrossDeducted": 952,
        "totalTaxDeducted": 152
      }
    ],
    "ignoreChildPriceUpdates": false,
    "deductedPrice": 800,
    "deductionFactor": 0,
    "totalPrice": 800,
    "totalPriceGross": 952,
    "totalPriceGrossDeducted": 952,
    "priceType": "WithTotal",
    "shortText": "Main Building",
    "comissionStatus": "Undefined",
    "itemNumber": {
      "id": "21eaf9cd-10f4-4073-bef8-67a490e18ec5",
      "stringRepresentation": "01.",
      "isSchemaCompliant": true,
      "itemNumberSchema": {
        "totalLength": 7,
        "tiers": [
          {
            "length": 2,
            "type": "Numeric",
            "tierType": "Group",
            "isLot": false
          },
          {
            "length": 2,
            "type": "Numeric",
            "tierType": "Group",
            "isLot": false
          },
          {
            "length": 3,
            "type": "Numeric",
            "tierType": "Position",
            "isLot": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "identifiers": [
        "01"
      ],
      "isLot": false
    },
    "elementType": "ServiceSpecificationGroupDto",
    "isLot": false,
    "projectCatalogues": [],
    "catalogueReferences": [],
    "id": "5b92177e-41c8-43e8-adfd-8b4e4946bc37",
    "gaebXmlId": "ID_1e260d6b-8004-41e9-b588-2ee17b026025",
    "elementTypeDiscriminator": "ServiceSpecificationGroupDto"
  },
  "parentId": "1631664479685x951949959612072000",
  "parentType": "project",
  "fileId": "1631664479685x951949959612072000",
  "uniqueId": "5b92177e-41c8-43e8-adfd-8b4e4946bc37"
}

console.log(obj["402a9267-0d36-412f-84ee-918db077f4bb"]);
```

I would like to access to it's parent .id (something like) obj["760e8c53-eef6-473f-992e-84f0fc8ab235"] as we use . (dot) to access to values, how I could access to his nearest parent .id ?

Not even sure this is possible

Comment: This will help: https://github.com/tckerr/walk#halting-the-walk - any way you look at it you must walk/traverse/iterate the tree at least once.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm trying to do without external libraries, just with native js. Don't you think it's possible ? Thanks

Comment: The library is written in TypeScript which compiles to JavaScript without any additional dependencies. Maybe you could draw inspiration from it or similar libraries? If you’re asking about a built way to just access a parent of a random property, there really isn’t one.